# Wrong element placement in small resolutions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A couple of days ago returned to finish an old project and decided to change its UI to be tabbed for mobile devices. Somewhere from the net found a pure CSS design which works fine except that child elements in each tab appear below the 3rd tab instead of the corresponding label (see the picture). The idea is that all elements belonging to each tab to appear below the corresponding tab label, ie input fields for `ADD` tab to appear under `ADD` label and so on ...
[image]

After 2 days I still can't find where is the error in the CSS. If I remove the 4 ordering lines in `.tabs` `.tab` rule elements go where they should be in small screen/browser widths but in wider ones label positions are broken. Can you help for that? HTML and CSS are also attached:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  main {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  div {
    flex-basis: 66%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
  .tabs .tab,  .tabs label {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: NaN;
    -webkit-order: initial;
    -ms-flex-order: initial;
    order: initial;
  }

  .tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}

html {
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%; /* fix for android devices */
  /* overflow: hidden; */ /* fix for android devices, currently disabled for desktops */
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 112%;
}

main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*textarea {
  resize: none;
}*/

input {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs label {
  /*-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;*/
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: background ease 0.2s;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs .tab {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 100;
  -webkit-order: 99;
  -ms-flex-order: 99;
  order: 99;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label { background: white; color: black; }

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab { display: block; }

.product-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fileuploadbutton {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fileuploadbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #0080ff;
  border-color: #80ecff;
  color: #80ecff;
}

.addproductbutton, .searchproductbutton, .sellproductbutton {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #bfdfff;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.addproductbutton:hover, .searchproductbutton:hover, .sellproductbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #0080ff;
  border-color: #80ecff;
  color: #80ecff;
}

.new-product-results, .search-product-results, .sell-product-results {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Sales and Inventory Control System</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Sales and Inventory Control System</h1>
    </header>

<main>
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabone">Add</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" id="newproductparameters" name="productparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name" autofocus>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="number" name="number" required placeholder="SKU">
        <input type="text" id="category" name="category" required placeholder="Category">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" name="quantity" required placeholder="Quantity">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="available" name="available" required placeholder="Available">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="price" name="price" required placeholder="Price">
        <input type="text" id="info" name="info" required placeholder="Additional product info">
        <label>Choose product pictures<br /><input class="fileuploadbutton" id="pictures" name="pictures" type="file" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg"></label>
        <button class="addproductbutton" type="submit" id="addproduct" onclick="addProduct(); return false;">Add</button>
        <output class="new-product-results" id="newproductresults" style="text-align: center" name="newproductresults">New product results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo">Search</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" name="searchproductparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="searchnumber" name="searchnumber" required placeholder="SKU" autofocus>
        <button class="searchproductbutton" type="submit" id="searchproduct" onclick="searchProduct(); return false;">Search</button>
        <output class="search-product-results" id="searchresults" style="text-align: center" name="searchresults">Search results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabthree">
    <label for="tabthree">Sell</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" name="sellproductparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="sellnumber" name="sellnumber" required placeholder="SKU" autofocus>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="sellquantity" name="sellquantity" required placeholder="Quantity">
        <select name="soldin" id="soldin" required>
          <option value="">-Choose where it was sold-</option>
          <option value="site">SITE</option>
          <option value="fb">Facebook</option>
          <option value="olx">OLX</option>
          <option value="bazar">Bazar.bg</option>
          <option value="phone">Telephone</option>
          <option value="viber">Viber</option>
        </select>
        <button class="sellproductbutton" type="submit" id="sellproduct" onclick="sellProduct(); return false;">Sell</button>
        <output class="sell-product-results" id="sellproductresults" style="text-align: center" name="sellproductresults">Sell product results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: so what's the result you want

Comment: I think he wants the "add" to be in the group of other buttons. But its super unclear so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do it with order on reponsive screens < 45em's.. see snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  main {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  div {
    flex-basis: 66%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
  .tabs .tab,  .tabs label {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: NaN;
    -webkit-order: initial;
    -ms-flex-order: initial;
    order: initial;
  }
  .tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab{
    order: 0;
  }

  .tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}

html {
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%; /* fix for android devices */
  /* overflow: hidden; */ /* fix for android devices, currently disabled for desktops */
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 112%;
}

main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*textarea {
  resize: none;
}*/

input {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs label {
  /*-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;*/
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: background ease 0.2s;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs .tab {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 100;
  -webkit-order: 99;
  -ms-flex-order: 99;
  order: 99;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label { background: white; color: black; }

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab { display: block; }

.product-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fileuploadbutton {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fileuploadbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #0080ff;
  border-color: #80ecff;
  color: #80ecff;
}

.addproductbutton, .searchproductbutton, .sellproductbutton {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #bfdfff;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.addproductbutton:hover, .searchproductbutton:hover, .sellproductbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #0080ff;
  border-color: #80ecff;
  color: #80ecff;
}

.new-product-results, .search-product-results, .sell-product-results {
  border: 2px solid #bfdfff;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Sales and Inventory Control System</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Sales and Inventory Control System</h1>
    </header>

<main>
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabone">Add</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" id="newproductparameters" name="productparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name" autofocus>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="number" name="number" required placeholder="SKU">
        <input type="text" id="category" name="category" required placeholder="Category">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" name="quantity" required placeholder="Quantity">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="available" name="available" required placeholder="Available">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="price" name="price" required placeholder="Price">
        <input type="text" id="info" name="info" required placeholder="Additional product info">
        <label>Choose product pictures<br /><input class="fileuploadbutton" id="pictures" name="pictures" type="file" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg"></label>
        <button class="addproductbutton" type="submit" id="addproduct" onclick="addProduct(); return false;">Add</button>
        <output class="new-product-results" id="newproductresults" style="text-align: center" name="newproductresults">New product results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo">Search</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" name="searchproductparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="searchnumber" name="searchnumber" required placeholder="SKU" autofocus>
        <button class="searchproductbutton" type="submit" id="searchproduct" onclick="searchProduct(); return false;">Search</button>
        <output class="search-product-results" id="searchresults" style="text-align: center" name="searchresults">Search results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabthree">
    <label for="tabthree">Sell</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <form class="product-form" name="sellproductparameters" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="number" min="0" id="sellnumber" name="sellnumber" required placeholder="SKU" autofocus>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="sellquantity" name="sellquantity" required placeholder="Quantity">
        <select name="soldin" id="soldin" required>
          <option value="">-Choose where it was sold-</option>
          <option value="site">SITE</option>
          <option value="fb">Facebook</option>
          <option value="olx">OLX</option>
          <option value="bazar">Bazar.bg</option>
          <option value="phone">Telephone</option>
          <option value="viber">Viber</option>
        </select>
        <button class="sellproductbutton" type="submit" id="sellproduct" onclick="sellProduct(); return false;">Sell</button>
        <output class="sell-product-results" id="sellproductresults" style="text-align: center" name="sellproductresults">Sell product results</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Kresimir, there's a problem with your solution (it works with 5 tabs) - last tab is overlapping somewhere in the middle of input fields of the other tabs and trying to click on them opens that last tab. Any ideas? Here's the project's repo [https://github.com/quantuumsnot/sics](https://github.com/quantuumsnot/sics)